# Open ftp:// links with nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gnome, ftp, nautilus

This question is exactly what is says on the tin.

At the moment, with default settings, all ftp:// links (even bookmarks in the Places menu created with "Connect to Server", which opens in Nautilus the first time) open in Firefox (which can only read, not write). So I have to copy the URL into nautilus to open it with nautilus to save files.

How can I make these links open in nautilus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the associations in `gconf-editor`. Expand **desktop -> gnome -> url-handlers** and find the entry for FTP and change the command to your preferences.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't work, try to edit or add:

`x-scheme-handler/ftp=nautilus`
to `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

or

`x-scheme-handler/ftp=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`
to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`